# openRoad stored procedure output parameter

Tags: ingres

I'm a newbie in Ingres and OpenRoad. Is it possible to have a database stored procedure return two values?
I want to return an integer and a varchar to use in multiple OpenRoad frames.
I can create the stored procedure but the parameter does not return the varchar value. I'm using the return value as my integer variable.

Answer (score 0):

I used out parameters to solve this

Comment: Can you be more specific/detailed? As is, this answer doesn't seem very useful to anyone else encountering the same problem